# How can I iterate through the entire tensor of an unknown shape in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

Let's say I have an arbitrary NN.module. I want to iterate through all the learnable weights of this neural network and then modify every weight.

For example I want to do something like this (where model is Resnet50):

```
with torch.no_grad():
  for param in model.parameters():
    print(type(param), param.size())
    param[0][0][0][0] = 0.5
    print(param[0][0][0][0])
    break

<class 'torch.nn.parameter.Parameter'> torch.Size([64, 3, 7, 7])
tensor(0.5000, device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
```

However, I want to do this to all weights without knowing the dimensions of params. Is there anyway to do this or would I need to do some recursion?

Comment: Seems like you've already solved your problem. Just replace `param[0][0][0][0] = 0.5` with `param = param * 0 + 0.5` or `param[:] = 0.5` or `param = <custom tensor of same size>` something to that effect

Comment: @DerekG What's the meaning of this syntax? I don't know what the shape of param is nor the size. Also I am just trying to do change one element at at a time to 0.5 value. Not everything to 0.5 at once

Comment: If your code given above doesn't solve the issue, then you need to post more code and explanation because the issue you are trying to solve is not evident to the reader.

Comment: If you want to change all the weights in `param` to the same thing, use the code in the first comment. If you want to change each individually you can iterate over `param`

Comment: @DerekG yeah I'm asking how can I iterate over param. For example, param[0][0]... = 0.5 then do some function, then do param[1][0]... then do some function then param[2][0]... then param[0][1]... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over a tensor of arbitary size and number of dimensions by flattening it.

```
for param in model.parameters():
  shape = param.shape # store original shape
  flat = param.flatten()
  for i in range(len(flat)):
      flat[i] = ... modify item, unclear what you want to do...

  # return to original shape
  param = flat.view(shape)
```